# Prove that $F:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow L(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R})$ is an isomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra

> Consider $S$ an $n \times n$ invertible matrix, and for any $v\in
> \mathbb{R}^n$, let $T_v$ be the linear transformation from
>    $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$ such that $T_v(w)=v^T(Sw)$ for any $w\in
>  \mathbb{R}^n$. Suppose $F:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow
>  L(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R})$ is a mapping defined by $F(v)=T_v$. Prove
>   that $F$ is an isomorphism.

To show that $F$ is an isomorphism, I know we need to show that it is a linear transformation and that it is invertible. To show that $F$ is a linear transformation we can do

$$F(av_1+bv_2)=aT_{v_1}+bT_{v_2} = aF(T_{v_1})+bF(T_{v_2})$$

So $F$ is indeed a linear transformation. However, I'm having trouble showing that $F$ is invertible. We can write $B = T_v=v^T(Sw)$, but what are we trying to solve for to show that $F$ is invertible?

Comment: How do you define $\;v(Sw)\;$ ? I think a transpose is lacking here, no matter whther you consider row or column vectors.

Comment: Because both $\mathbb R^n$ and $L(\mathbb R^n , \mathbb R)$ has the same dimensions, it suffices to show that the kernel of $F$ is $\{0\}$.

Comment: @John that presupposes that we know that the dual space is also $n$-dimensional (perhaps by selecting the canonical dual basis).

Comment: @Omnomnomnom One could just prove it directly, since it's common to know at this point the dimension of $L(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^m)$ is $nm$ by identification with the $m\times n$ matrices.

Comment: @neuguy good point

Answer (score 0):

What you really need to do is show that $F$ is both injective and surjective.

**One approach:** Note that $F$ is injective iff it has a non-trivial kernel.  Is there any non-zero vector $v$ such that $F_v = 0$?  How do we know?

For any $f \in L(\Bbb R^n ,\Bbb R)$, can we find a vector $v$ such that $f = T_v$?  How?

**Another approach:** you could also do this by taking a basis $v_1,\dots,v_n$ of $\Bbb R^n$ and showing that $T_{v_1},\dots,T_{v_n}$  is a basis for $L(\Bbb R^n,\Bbb R)$.

---

**Construction of inverse:** For example, we can define
$$
F^{-1}(T) = 
\pmatrix{T(S^{-1}e_1)\\
T(S^{-1}e_2)\\
\vdots\\
T(S^{-1}e_n)
}
$$
Where $e_j = (\overbrace{0,\dots,0}^{j-1},1,0,\dots,0)^T$

Comment: Then what is the inverse of $F$?

Comment: I could construct it if I really wanted to, but doing so is not necessary to answer the question you need to answer.

Comment: @Hailey also, did you mean $T_v(w) = v^T Sw$?  Otherwise, I have no idea what $v(Sw)$ should mean.

Comment: Yes, that should be $v^T$. I am still interested in the inverse if you can show me how to construct it.

Comment: See my latest edit

Comment: Can you show some steps please?

Comment: Again, there really is no reason to: proving a transformation is invertible does not require constructing its inverse.  If you're so eager to construct this inverse, you should post another question with that specific goal.

Comment: I'm honestly just curious about what the inverse is. It was posted as an extra "practice" exercise, so I'm trying to see how to construct it.